# Open Youtube Application to a video/Web Browser to a video on Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I would need to open a youtube link when clicking on the related element on my list.
How can I do this in codename one?
(Opening the system web browser to this link would be fine)

Answer (score 2):

To open the link in your default browser, call:

```
Display.getInstance().execute("https://www.youtube.com");
```